# Find the common string in a subgroup in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm trying to clean a list, by removing duplicates. For example:

```
 bb = ['Gppe (Aspirin Combined)', 
       'Gppe Cap (Migraine)',  
       'Gppe Tab', 
       'Abilify', 
       'Abilify Maintena', 
       'Abstem', 
       'Abstral']
```

Ideally, I need to get the following list:

```
 bb = ['Gppe', 
       'Abilify', 
       'Abstem', 
       'Abstral']
```

What I tried:

1. Split the list and remove duplicates (a naive approach)

   `list(set(sorted([j for bb_i in bb for j in bb_i.split(' ')])))`

which leaves a lot of 'rubbish':

```
['(Aspirin',
 '(Migraine)',
 'Abilify',
 'Abstem',
 'Abstral',
 'Cap',
 'Combined)',
 'Gppe',
 'Maintena',
 'Tab']
```

2. Find the most frequent word:

`Counter(['Gppe (Aspirin Combined)', 'Gppe Cap (Migraine)',  'Gppe Tab').most_common(1)[0][0]`

But I'm not sure how to find similar words (a group)??

I am wondering, whether one can use a kind of 'groupby()' and first group by names and then remove duplicates within those names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do, assuming you want the unique first *word* of each string:

```
bb = ['Gppe (Aspirin Combined)',
       'Gppe Cap (Migraine)',
       'Gppe Tab',
       'Abilify',
       'Abilify Maintena',
       'Abstem',
       'Abstral']


result = set(map(lambda x: x.split()[0], bb))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Gppe', 'Abstral', 'Abilify', 'Abstem'}
```

If you want a list of unique elements in the order of appearance, you could do:

```
bb = ['Gppe (Aspirin Combined)',
       'Gppe Cap (Migraine)',
       'Gppe Tab',
       'Abilify',
       'Abilify Maintena',
       'Abstem',
       'Abstral']

seen = set()
result = []
for e in bb:
    key = e.split()[0]
    if key not in seen:
        result.append(key)
        seen.add(key)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Gppe', 'Abilify', 'Abstem', 'Abstral']
```

As an alternative to the first solution you could do:

1. Suggested by @Jean-FrançoisFabre `{x.split()[0] for x in bb}`
2. Suggested by @RoadRunner `set(x.split()[0] for x in bb)`

Comment: `set(map(lambda x: x.split()[0], bb))` that's ugly. A set comprehension would probably be more readable like `{x.split()[0] for x in bb}`. Code-golfed ya

Comment: Could also do `set(x.split()[0] for x in bb)`

Comment: Also if you want to maintain order, `list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(x.split()[0] for x in bb).keys())` is another way.

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks for you all! It's always great to learn neat and pythonic methods

Answer (score 5):

If order doesn't matter, you can use a set comprehension:

```
res = list({x.split()[0] for x in bb})
```

If order matters and you have Python 3.6 or higher, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
res = list({x.split()[0]:None for x in bb})
```

If order matters and you have Python 3.5 or lower, you can use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
res = list(OrderedDict((x.split()[0],None) for x in bb))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try split every item and collect only the first string before separator(space)

```
print(list(set(item.split(' ',1)[0] for item in bb)))
```

This looks of getting what you need:

```
['Abilify', 'Abstem', 'Gppe', 'Abstral']
```